# Change capacitor

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, soldering, circuit-protection, electricity

I have got a question about capacitor.Used in monitor.
Here is my "Broken" capacitor[image]

[image]

And here is my "New" capacitor.
With same parameters but they both have a different I don't know how it's proper call but i think it's a name of them.
Anyway old"Broken" has number W6A7 but new has E232.
Does those numbers have a sense?Or i can just put "new" and do not afraid for my monitor?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4OMU.jpg)
[image]

Thanks in advance!
P.S.Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does those numbers have a sense?Or i can just put "new" and do not
> afraid for my monitor?*

Those numbers are probably just specific to the manufacturer. The important numbers for performance are: -

- 100 uF
- 450 volts
- 105 degC
- Rated ripple current at the typical circuit operating frequency
- Lifetime

The ripple current may not be shown on the device but the three values listed prior to ripple should be. However, you can't assume that because the rated ripple current isn't shown, that your replacement will be effective in your circuit or reliable.

Sometimes the lifetime rating is shown - this is the number of hours that the capacitor is judged to be able to work for without serious performance deterioration at the temperature value on full voltage and ripple current. So, when making comparisons, you should always check that the potential replacement is going to last as long (or longer) that the original device.

See also [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490969/replacing-these-capacitors/490973#490973) - it gives you more information on temperature rating and lifetime values, so you can make better comparisons.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply!Short answer is that i can use new because "new" have a relevent parametres.I know that if i want much long work is better go to shop and by new capacitor with good lifetime.But in my case i don't mind, if after couple months i have to again replace capacitor.I was concerned about do not  damage a controller board.So again Thank you for help!

Comment: @Igor um, a failing capacitor can definitely damage your controller board, so your considerations about "oh I can replace that in a couple of months" don't work out.

Comment: Yes,but those parameters such a voltage,uF,and temperature fits.What about ripple current on capacitor there is no sign of it on the body.I doubht if i go to shop(with broken capacitor) and find proper  with parametr i even can't determine on body.
Or i can measure it somehow?

Comment: @Igor you ask the shop for the data sheet of the component they are trying to sell you and take a look at it. If you don't know what part the original is (maybe those letters and numbers hint at the manufacturer and product range) then you have to dig a little deeper or, just buy the best you can and say a small prayer.

Comment: Ok,thanks for your help i appreciate that.I already put in new capacitor and it's worked at least now,but tomorrow i will call to shop and ask about ripple current.

Comment: @Igor quite likely you should choose a capacitor that has a ripple current specification at 100 kHz - electrolytics of this value and voltage tend to be used in switching converters that operate at 100 kHz (plus or minus a few tens of kHz) and, the best cap to choose is suitably specified at 100 kHz typically. [What you should consider doing next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).