# Capacitor Lifetime

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors, electrolytic-capacitor

Can anyone some sample calculation on how to calculate the lifetime on an Aluminum Electrolytic capacitor who's Endurance value (Assumed as Lifetime value is 2000 hours at 105degC).

[image]

The manufacturer also gives a formula like below,

[image]

My working :

The below table is how much I am going to operate the capacitor at each temperature. And I am planning to use the capacitor for a lifetime of 10years which approximately comes to 87660 hours (considering leap year).

[image]

Can someone tell me the logic behind the below calculation.

[image]

Why is the last column values multiplied with 2000 (2000 h cap lifetime value)?

Comment: Where did the table come from? Did you create it? If so, why did you choose to make those calculations? If not, what was the source?

Comment: [Similar question and answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490969/replacing-these-capacitors)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I did not make those calculations. I found them from a file which was already done by some unknown person. Do you know how those calculations are made?

Comment: @Andyaka, thank you for the link. Do you have some idea on the above calculation images posted in the question?

Comment: I don't recognize the calculation images and have no idea where they came from. The answer I linked should be clear in that respect as it uses the same formulas.